# Windows git: Fatal: TaskCanceledException encountered

Tags: git

I have recently updated my git (2.7.4.windows.1). Since then pulling from github produces output like this:

```
$ git pull --rebase
Fatal: TaskCanceledException encountered.
Current branch ABC-123_Something is up to date.
```

The `Fatal: TaskCanceledException encountered.` appears after a boring 20 seconds and then everything works out just fine. I haven't found anything on the net and I would like to avoid wasting that 20 seconds over and over again.

Comment: No idea why this happens, but I can confirm it happens to me, too. What's in your git config?

Comment: @gvoysey http://pastebin.com/9Pa5Rc8t

Comment: http://pastebin.com/D0yANCeG

Comment: @gvoysey AFAIK I have found the solution. See my answer!

Comment: I got the fatal error msg immediately on a "git push", not after 20 sec. I then ran the suggested solution "git config ..." and re-ran  "git push". At that time I had a delay of about 10 sec. So I suspect that the first "git push" did not succeed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The credential helper handling changed since the last version that I used. The *systemwide gitconfig* (as TortoiseGit calls it) contained a section:

```
[credential]
    helper = manager
```

I think it is some leftover from previous versions. I deleted it and the delay and the error message haven't happened since. Victory! :-)

Comment: I don't believe this is the actual solution; that section says "use the [windows credential manager](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) to cache your credentials for https:// repos", which I normally do want to do.

Comment: I haven't changed anything else. I will test adding it back tomorrow.

Comment: @gvoysey Tested it finally. Added it back and the problem reappeared.

Comment: Agree with this answer, I had the same message and didn't know why untill I read it... In my case, I ran the command `git config --global credential.helper wincred` in order to be able to do pull/push from github without writting credentials everytime, that was a long time ago, recently, I changed my login in Windows 10, from local account to outlook account 3 days ago, since then, the exception message appeared. Once I read this, I ran the same git command I mentioned before and the message is gone... Sorry for the long comment, I wanted to write my example case. May be useful for someone.

Comment: @HugoAllexisCardona thank you. `git config --global credential.helper wincred` worked perfectly. :)

Comment: Glad to help! regards!

Comment: TaskCanceledException comes out of Git Credentials Manager for Windows tool (it's written in .Net, hence .Net exception), and its combination with timeout tells me that it probably can't connect to github to authenticate - maybe it got proxy issues. Dunno though why everything works after you removing this line from config.

Comment: @HugoAllexisCardona thank you for your post. git config --global credential.helper wincred worked for me as well.

Answer (score 37):

None of the above helped me... So my fix is to remove *manager* helper from git's system config:

```
git config --system --unset credential.helper
```

If you got *permission denied*, invoke above command after running cmd as administrator.

Comment: With this now I am just asked any time when I am trying to pull to enter my credentials. Thy only difference is now I am not getting the error message .... So not the best solution

Answer (score 33):

I just ran into this same problem and, in case it is missed in the comments for the accepted answer, the fix is:

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

Credit to [Hugo Allexis Cardona](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1797127/hugo-allexis-cardona)

Answer (score 19):

There appears to be some relation between the setting of proxy options inside your global .gitconfig file and the need to clear your credential helper setting from the system level. I recently removed git http-proxy and https-proxy settings from my file for security reasons, and began receiving this message, then a pause, then a prompt to log into my external git repository. This happened with every fetch, push or pull. I didn't want to replace the proxy settings in my .gitconfig, so here are the steps that worked for me:

`git config --list --system`

`git config --list --global`

These will give you listings of all your system and global level settings. This confirmed that it was set to credential.helper=manager in the system namespace, and credential.helper=wincred in the global namespace. To remove the interference on the system level:

`git config --system --unset credential.helper`

All git command reverted to normal, with no error messages or delays.

Comment: I used too git config --system --unset credential.helper --global
thank you for help!!!

Answer (score 8):

This happens because there is a clash of git .config settings in the global and system level. In my case, the credential helper in system was set to `manager` while in global, it was set to `wincred`.
You can check it using the below commands:

`git config --list --system`

`git config --list --global`

I changed the system one from manager to `wincred` and it worked. Change it using the below command.

`git config --global credential.helper wincred`

Answer (score 3):

This can also be triggered by a bad network connection. I sometimes have to switch to using my phone as a hotspot to stop Git giving the following error:

```
fatal: TaskCanceledException encountered.
   A task was canceled.
```

Perhaps it's an authentication timeout that triggers it?

Answer (score 2):

This error can also happen when your Git hoster is down, so check the status page (eg, [GitHub status](https://www.githubstatus.com/)) to see if there is any incident on the hoster side before trying the other solutions here.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i had to to set up the proxy

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:80
```

Comment: Try setting the environment variable for your account instead of recording your username and password in a plain text file. Just head to Start>>Edit Environment Variables for my Account, and set HTTP_PROXY to the same value you used above. Git will pick up on it, and conveniently, so will NPM or Yarn, eliminating the need to duplicate the same values across multiple files.