# git pull `TaskEndedException encountered` error

Tags: git

I am trying to update my codes from an existing github repository and tried git pull origin but it was coming up the error:

```
git pull
fatal: a TaskEndedException encountered
```

Comment: To learn more about `git pull`, I suggest reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-is-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch

Comment: As for the error, I have never seen that before but looks like someone solved it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36309363/windows-git-fatal-taskcanceledexception-encountered

Comment: As a programmer, the first thing to do is to google the error message. Someone else has almost certainly seen the same error before and posted somewhere on the Internet about it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows git: Fatal: TaskCanceledException encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36309363/windows-git-fatal-taskcanceledexception-encountered)